# How to insert column in already existing table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am creating table Account with limited data i.e. with id , name and reference.
If I get array of MembersIntersection then based on their size I want to add those extra columns in already created table

```
type Account struct {
    ID         string `json:"Id,omitempty" validate:"max=36"`
    Name       string `json:"name,omitempty" validate:"required,max=255"`
    Reference  string `json:"reference,omitempty" validate:"required,max=64"`
    MembersIntersection []DimensionMemberIntersection `json:"dimensionMemberIntersection,omitempty" 
}
```

How to do this using gorm?

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to explain what you mean with "I am creating table Account" ? do you want to add a SQL table to your database ? or do you want to build a table as in "an array containing the result of a query" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use the Gorm migrator interface. **I wouldn't recommend doing this though**, basing the table structure on user input doesn't sound like a good idea. Maybe you could store this variable input in a JSON column?

Here is an example using the gorm migrator interface. The full docs are [here](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html)

You will need version 2 of gorm.

```golang
type DimensionMemberIntersection string

type Account struct {
    ID         string 
    Name       string 
    Reference  string 
    MembersIntersection []DimensionMemberIntersection
    // This assumes the underlying type of DimensionMemberIntersection is string
}

account := Account{}

for _, col := range account.MembersIntersection {
    if !db.Migrator().HasColumn(&Account{}, col) {
        db.Migrator().AddColumn(&Account{}, col)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i need to update my go version.